# Regarding Function in Python

Tags: python, function, definition

I am new to Python. I discover that in the arguments of e.g., `annotate`, it is allow to put `xy=...`, `xytext=....`, is it a feature of Python? If yes how do we define a function in python that allow this?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.annotate('Here is something special', xy = (2, 1), xytext=(1,5),arrowprops={'facecolor': 'r'})
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? If it really is *"can Python functions have named arguments?"*, perhaps you should [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a python's feature, called keyword parameters.
Functions can also be called using keyword arguments of the form "keyword = value". You can read about this topic [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html).

keyword arguments is not different than normal arguments except order isn't important. There is nothing special to do in the definition. For example:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    pass

my_func(1, 2)
my_func(b=2, a=1)

# Both of them get the same results
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you want to do, but I think that this part of the Python documentation might answer your question:

https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html

Comment: Ok, we came up with the answer at the same time, but Miguel's is more detailed.

Comment: An alternative link from sometime in the 21st century: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments